# Disk2VHD and Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, vhd, hal

I want to virtualize a physical machine and I used Disk2Vhd to convert the Hard drive to a .vhd file.

My issue is that when I attach this vhd in Hyper-V, and try to install

`"Integration Services", I get the message "HAL Upgrade Required"`,

and after sometime,

`"You must restart your system before Hyper-V Integration services can be installed. Do you want to restart now"`

The problem is that these steps get repeated again and again and I am never able to install the Integration services.

Addition Info:

```
Server: Windows 2008 R2
Guest Machine: Windows 2003 Server with SP2
```

Any suggestions??

Thanks

Comment: hmm the hal upgrade message is normal as is the integration component message.  I'd look at the hyper-v logs under the integration components and see what its saying there!

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Did you modify the multi-boot (boot.ini?) file to remove the other "disk2vhd" boot option or somehow change the default boot?

Comment: I changed the default order of operating systems to always boot from the correct location- I did not remove the other boot option

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After going through forums.. finally found the solution. (the link is [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverhyperv/thread/7ea051c7-ac94-4f34-b6f6-8d75f4225173) )

When you start the VM under Hyper-V, you get a Multi-Boot option,

```
Disk2Vhd Windows Server 2003 Standard
Windows Server 2003 Standard
```

You must boot the system with `Windows Server 2003 Standard` and not with Disk2Vhd one.. Thanks to the guy who found out!!! - I wasted almost a week on this, glad that it's finally working

Comment: GREAT!!! I've been having this problem on a VM (which didn't P2V myself) for a while, and completely overlooked the multiboot issue... would never have guessed it!

Comment: Thanks, helped me with a similar problem involving an in-place repair of (ancient) WinXP to change from OEM to Retail license not booting after completing the first part of the upgrade (all in Hyper-V on Win10Pro). Editing boot.ini in the .vhdx and removing the Disk2Vhd line completely before booting up and running the repair resolved that issue and a couple others I'd had to work around other ways. Thanks for setting me on the right path! (As to why I'm running WinXP in 2016, it's not pretty, but it is saving a business $20k for a bit: 32-bit only industrial automation software.)